# Struts2- URL tag - Hide query String

Tags: url, struts2, tags

After a lot of research on stackoverflow i'm posting this question as i could not find a solution for the issue.

Requirement Scenario : Update a customer from a list of customers based on each customer id as parameter.

Solution tried: Based on the customer Id received from the jsp, pass it to the Action as Struts2 url tag.

Issue Faced - Query String visible on the URL.
    http://foo.com/Struts2Example/getCustomerAction?customerId=2

Questions :

1. Can we not hide the query string if we use struts Url tag?
2. If we cannot hide the using query string while using Url tag? what is the alternative for the above scenario.

Code for struts.xml,jsp and action below -

```html
<h2>All Customers Details</h2>

<s:if test="customerList.size() > 0">
    <table border="1px" cellpadding="8px">
        <tr>
            <th>Customer Id</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Created Date</th>
        </tr>
        <s:iterator value="customerList" status="userStatus">
            <tr>
                <td><s:url var="editCustomer" action="getCustomerAction">
                        <s:param name="customerId" value="%{customerId}" />
                    </s:url>

                    <p>
                        <s:a href="%{editCustomer}">
                            <s:property value="customerId" />
                        </s:a>
                    </p></td>

                <td><s:property value="firstname" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="lastname" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="age" /></td>
                <td><s:date name="createdDate" format="dd/MM/yyyy" /></td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </table>
</s:if>
<br />
<br />
```

struts.xml-

```xml
<!-- Get Customer Details - To Pre-Populate the form to update a Customer -->
    <action name="getCustomerAction" method="getCustomerById"
        class="com.hcl.customer.action.CustomerAction">
        <result name="success">pages/customerForm.jsp </result>
    </action>
```

Customer Action class-

```java
public class CustomerAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven {

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomerAction.class);

Customer customer = new Customer();

List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
CustomerDAO customerDAO = new CustomerDAOImpl();

public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

//Set Customer onto Value Stack
public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
    return customerList;
}

//Set Customer List onto Value Stack
public void setCustomerList(List<Customer> customerList) {
    this.customerList = customerList;
}

public String execute() throws Exception {
    return SUCCESS;
}

public Object getModel() {
    return customer;
}



// Edit customer details, it will retrieve the records based on customerId
//SkipValidation is used to skip the validate()
@SkipValidation
public String getCustomerById() {

    logger.info("** Customer Id to edit ** " + customer.getCustomerId());

    customer = customerDAO.customerById(customer.getCustomerId());

    return SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to hide the id? If you store the value on the client side anyone can look at the source and get it. You can of course use post to send the result, however consider the need for the user to bookmark the page. Really the answer is security... should this user be able to access this customer id? If not then it should not be allowed in any case.

Comment: Yeah the user can bookmark a page like that... but the question says `Update a customer` while the URL is `**getCustomer**Action?customerId=2`... something strange here :>

Comment: @AndreaLigios - The scenario is, to update a customer, i'll have to pre-populate his details on the form. To fetch the details, i query the database with the customerId.

Comment: @Quaternion - First part of your question -Why do you want to hide the id? Since the query string is visible, the user can re-trigger the action. so to avoid the same, i need to hide the query string. Secondly, since i'm not using a form here and when i try to give the method as post, the flow tries to look for a method as post in the action class.Plz let me know if i'm wrong here. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If you hide the URL but the user press F5 multiple times after sending the request, it'll send a lot of requests the same. There are other ways (discussed multiple times on SO) to prevent that...

Comment: You post forms, if you are not going to use a form your final option is ajax.

Comment: page not found for [the provided link](http://foo.com/Struts2Example/getCustomerAction?customerId=2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some unordered considerations:

- use different Actions (with the execute method only), or different Methods of the same Action, to perform different "actions";
- The name of each Action/Method should match the operation performed and be self-explanatory, for example you should have an `editCustomer` method (or Action) to **edit** the customer and a `getCustomer` method (or Action) to **obtain** the customer;
- The GET HTTP method should be used to read data, while the POST HTTP method should be used to send data; every non-reading operation *should* ideally be performed through POST; using GET to send data is an old bad practice born 20 years ago and never died :/ The reasons to use POST are the hidden URL, a higher load capacity, the ability to send binary data, etc...

That said, an URL like `http://foo.com/Struts2Example/getCustomerAction?customerId=2` should be visible (to be bookmarked for example), and ideally should be prettified (REST style, like StackOverflow): something like `http://foo.com/Struts2Example/Customer/2/`

An URL like `http://foo.com/Struts2Example/editCustomerAction?customerId=2` can't work, because you are not passing any other parameter; you know the id of the customer to edit, but not the data to alter...
It would become something like: 
`http://foo.com/Struts2Example/editCustomerAction?customerId=2&name=foo&lastname=bar&age=42`, that would work, but as said (and as ask in your question) should be hidden, and handled through POST.

If you are printing in the `source` of the page the `ID`s, then there should be no need to hide them to the user;

**What you need to do is to ensure that the user can't change the `ID`s outside the range you specified;** 
if you drawed in the page a list of customers with `ID {1,2,3}` you must block any attempt of the user to alter the id and trying to update the customer with `ID = 4`... to achieve that, simply store the list of ID in `session` before populating the page, and check the `ID`s returned by the page against your list. If they don't match, block the malicious operation.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your time and reply. Totally agree with you, w.r.t Action/Method names. Secondly, since i'm not using a form here, how can i make the request to the action as POST in my case? appreciate your help here.

Comment: You're welcome; why aren't you using a form ? And why can't you add one ? They're free :)

Comment: The scenario didn't need a form though. Since I'm not finding any other option suitable i might as well go with a form. Also since they are free ;) Thanks folks for the response to my queries. Appreciate it! Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, since you want to POST instead of GET, the scenario (now) needs a form ;)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative , is to encrypt the userID and send it back to the HTML page. Maintain the Mapping on the client side. When you submit the request , POST the encrypted value. The decryption/encyrption logic will be on the server side. 
This will add an overhead on the system but this is a decent enough trade-off to performance when compared to Security.
Also please take a look @ jcryption.org/info , its under MIT and GPL Licenses.

A simpler solution is to convert this into "POST" action so that the values are passed inside the HTTP Request Body. If its over HTTPS , it would be encrypted however you can still do the user id lookup using Google Developer Tools or IE9 Developer mode

Comment: converted the comments into answer. Please ignore comments. Thanks

Comment: @user1428716- thanks for the answer. In this scenario, since im not using a struts form, how can i achieve/convert the request to POST?